# Is there any way to use invalidatequeries in vue/nuxt?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

#### Version

- vue 2.6.14
- nuxt 2.15.8
- vue-query 1.26.0
- vue/composition-api 1.7.1

#### What I want to do

Due to slow website, I'm trying to use `vue-query` for our company's website.
When our admin page gets loaded, calls data from server and renders it. And this data is updated frequently.
But it doesn't need to be updated every time when loaded. So i'm trying to use `useQuery` to cache data and use it.
And, when each data gets updated, I want to use `invalidateQueries`

#### What I have done

Our website is built with nuxt lifecycle. Gets data at `asyncData`, and `POST`, or `PUT` data at method.
I could use `useQuery` to cache data. But, I have no idea how to `invalidateQuery` when user `POST`, or `PUT` data.

Here is some of our code

`/admin/index.vue` : this is our admin page which shows data to user

```js
<template>
...
</template>

<script setup>
// I could query and cache data by using this code
import { useQuery, useQueryClient } from 'vue-query'
import { defineComponent } from '@vue/composition-api'

const fetcher = async () => {
  const data = await axios(...)
  return data
}

export default defineComponent({
  const { refetch, data: blocks, isLoading } = useQuery(QUERY_KEY, () => fetcher(context.parent.$axios), {
      staleTime: 30 * 1000,
      initialData: () => {
        return queryClient.getQueryData(QUERY_KEY)
      }
    })
})
</script>
```

`/admin/edit.vue` : in this page, user can edit data

```js
<template>
  <div>
    ... some divs and forms
    <button @click="submit" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { useQuery, useQueryClient } from 'vue-query'
import { defineComponent } from '@vue/composition-api'

export default defineComponent ({
  methods: {
    async submit() {
      const { status, data } = await this.$axios.put('...', PAYLOAD_FROM_PAGE)
    }
})
</script>
```

In `edit` page, **when user put some data, I want to invalidateQuery that i have queried in admin page.** Tried to use `queryClient.invalidateQueries()` but it says it should be done in setup() lifecycle.

Is there any way to InvalidateQuery in my situation? I know my versions are pretty old, but it's quite large code, so upgrading version might take too long :(

Or should I rewrite my code in setup() lifecycle?